# Send Push Notification to all users as well as specific deviceTokens

Tags: php, json, rest, parse-platform

I am using the `Parse` `REST API` with PHP and am struggling to figure out how to do two things.

**Send to all users of a channel:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "alert": "This is a test!!",
    "sound": "default",
    "badge": 1
  },
  "where": {
    "channels": [
      "puc"
    ]}
  }
}
```

Sending that JSON gives me the error:

`{"code":102,"error":"equality needs a value instead of [puc] "}`

**Send to specific device token/tokens:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "alert": "This is a test!!",
    "sound": "default",
    "badge": 1
  },
  "where": {
    "channels": [
      "puc"
    ],
    "deviceToken": {
      "$in": [
        "DSFSAFJDSLKWRJKLJGLKASGLK"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Sending that JSON gives me the error:

`{"code":102,"error":"equality needs a value instead of [puc] "}`

What am I doing wrong? Can someone point me in the right direction for these two pushes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `channels` in a `where` clause, it only takes a value and not an array:

**Send to all users of a channel:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "alert": "This is a test!!",
    "sound": "default",
    "badge": 1
  },
  "where": {
    "channels": "puc"
    }
  }
}
```

**Send to specific device token/tokens:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "alert": "This is a test!!",
    "sound": "default",
    "badge": 1
  },
  "where": {
    "channels": "puc",
    "deviceToken": {
      "$in": [
        "DSFSAFJDSLKWRJKLJGLKASGLK"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you need to pass an array, you'll have to use `$in` like you did for "deviceToken".

Alternatively, when you don't have any other criteria than the channel, you don't need to put a where clause:

```
{
  "data": {
    "alert": "This is a test!!",
    "sound": "default",
    "badge": 1
  },
  "channels": [
    "puc"
  ]
}
```

You can find more example and information in the documentation: https://parse.com/docs/rest/guide/#push-notifications-sending-pushes